# Measuring Difference Between Two Sets of Likert Values

Tags: correlation, dataset, likert, statsmodels

I asked users to complete a likert survey (1-5) at the start of an activity and at the conclusion of the activity.

What is the best manner to show the rate of change/difference between these two result sets?
I was considering a Pearson correlation, but after thinking about things more I don't believe that it is the most appropriate correlation metric.

My data looks similar to below:

```
Before   After
1         2
1         2
2         2
3         3
3         4
4         2
```

**Result:** XXX?

Comment: One possibility is to calculate the sum of differences. Then calculate all possible sum of differences and see where (quantile / percentile) in the distribution of all possible differences the calculated sum sits.